# How to stop the namenode gracefully?

Tags: hadoop

Before running the hadoop stop namenode command we usually saveNamespace
Are there any more steps which are required before stopping namenode.
If yes please mention in order

Answer (score 1):

Save namespace is also not a mandatory command. One important step is to ensure that no jobs are running and no write/read operations are happening in the hadoop cluster. Because if you stop the namenode, all the operations which is dependent on hdfs will fail.

This includes, all data loads, data reads and all mapreduce jobs.

Comment: No I guess its a mandatory command.Suppose there are multiple datanodes which are running , we cannot shut down all the nodes so that they stop working and do not update the fsimage.

Comment: When you stop the name node, even if you are not using this savenamespace command, the cluster will work fine on the next start up.